# Does the Dottie number help solve the trisection or quintisection of a disc into equal-area parts by chords coming from a point on the circumference?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Since the problem of quartisection of a disc into four parts of the same area by chords coming from the same point can be solved via Dottie number as shown on this picture:

[image]

I wonder, whether the problems of trisection and quintisection of disc also can be solved using Dottie number.

Comment: What is the source for the claim about quartisection? I would start by studying the proof of that claim, to see whether it can be modified to give a result for trisection, quintisection, etc.

Comment: I see there's a proof at https://arxiv.org/pdf/2303.17962.pdf which suggests you could set up similar equations for trisection and see whether anything like Dottie's number drops out of the algebra.

Comment: @GerryMyerson https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4728910/on-a-problem-similar-to-the-goat-problem/4732728#4732728